# How do I access Ruby classes within a JAR built using Warbler from Java?

Tags: java, ruby, jruby, warbler

The method names in the compiled classes are weird and can not be used or called directly from Java. And as there are dependencies among Ruby files with modules and libraries, I'm not able to invoke methods on those classes directly using ScriptingEngine. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

This question gets to the root of the problem that you are experiencing with all of your other questions. JRuby and Warbler **do not** produce classes that you can just drop into a Java application. Ruby objects have a runtime library and all these other *things* that are needed.  Ultimately, you need to start a Ruby runtime, and that's what the [JRuby Embed API](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/RedBridge) is all about.